# Webrtc for arm64

Tags: objective-c, architecture, webrtc, arm64, libjingle

I am using the project found in this [link](https://github.com/Jonear/webrtcIosDemo) .
However, the mentioned project is developed for armv7 architecture and doesnt support arm64 architecture which became required for new apps in the store.

I tried to install updated librarie for arm64 and armv7  from [webrtc libraries](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios) 
The problem is that not all the compiled libraries replaced the existing one successfully( 12 libraries are replaced successfully and 14 libraries are given errors when replacing any of them with the existing one).

Libraries that are giving errors when updating it to arm 64 are:

```
Libaudio_coding_module
Libaudio_conference_mixer
Libaudio_device
Libaudio_processing
Libcommon_audio
Libjingle_audio_only
Libjingle_p2p
Libjingle
LibNetEq
LibmediaFile
Librtp_rtcp
Libsystem_wrappers
Libvoice_engine
Libwebrtc_utility.
```

Can anyone help me where i can get those librarires for arm64 architecture in order to use it in the webrtc project?

Thank you

Comment: When I first started compiling webrtc libraries I used [these build scripts](http://tech.pristine.io/tag/webrtc/). They are awesome and very easy to use (opposed to wasting hours trying to get your build environment setup correctly). I think it's your best bet, but I'm not so sure you can just replace the libs in that project and make it work without editing the source, a lot has changed after 64bit support was added.

Comment: I am desperate now :( HELP .. i can find projects of "webrtc rooms"  and compatible with arm64 but what i need is similar to the project that i mentioned in my post. where i can set my username and password and the host. I tried to copy libraries from room projects into the above project but no success

Comment: It sounds like you want a ready-made solution. There is no such thing available for free. If you want a custom voip app based on the webrtc standard, you are going to need to get your hands dirty with some code. It's just the way it is with webrtc right now. In the future some companies might release some wrappers for the native api (in fact, my company already did this for internal use), similar to how you can use webrtc in javascript, but we just aren't there yet, too much is still changing (like the recently added jsep support)